# Count 1 for every 22 in a column - DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column that shows the total number of tons a customer has ready at our different locations. What I want to do is have a formula that counts 1 for every 22 tons that occur in the ready product column.  For example. If ready = 44, I would want my count to show 2, if ready = 43, count should be 1.

My code is as follows:

```
Available to Ship =
IF (
    SOP_LOM2_Deliveries[Mode] = "Truck" || SOP_LOM2_Deliveries[Mode] = "Truck",
    ROUNDDOWN ( SOP_LOM2_Deliveries[Tons] / FLOOR ( 22, 1 ), 1 )
)
```

Right now the results I get vary. Sometimes I get incorrect numbers

[image: wrong numbers]

and other times I get correct numbers

[image: correct count]

Could anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong here?  Thank you!

Comment: I do not believe you show us everything. Seems you shor the roundup column?

Comment: Why do you have `FLOOR` in there?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I used it per a recommendation of a coworker when I explained the goal. I;m guessing tons/22 would also work just as well?

Comment: You can likely do it with ROUNDDOWN or FLOOR but using both is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
Available to Ship =
IF (
    SOP_LOM2_Deliveries[Mode] = "Truck" || SOP_LOM2_Deliveries[Mode] = "Truck",
    ROUNDDOWN ( SOP_LOM2_Deliveries[Tons] / 22, 0 )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I was really overthinking that wasn't I?  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Most problems come from overthinking. Asking a question to an external person is very useful because will bring a new perspective.